# How to set a global variable to contain the data returned from a method - Angular 6 service?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am trying to set a global variable inside my service to contain an array of objects returned from the database allowing methods within the service to access the array.

Currently I am logging to my console what is being returned from my method that is using an HTTP GET method to retrieve 500+ objects from my database.

I am trying to store what is returned from that GET method into a variable that I can pass into other methods to further manipulate the data.

I wasn't able to phrase my question properly in Google therefore I am not sure if I am asking it properly.

Here is my code...

```
const eventData = [];

@Injectable()
export class MonitoredEventService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private config: Config, private page: Page) {

    /*
    This is the original method I used to just get the events from the database
    */    
    }
    getMonitoredEvents2(batchSize, batchNumber) {
        return this.httpClient.get<MonitoredEvents>(this.config.getBaseUrl() + "/api/Events/" + batchSize + "/" +  batchNumber);
    }

    public getEvents(page: Page): Observable<PagedData<MonitoredEvents>> {
        return of(eventData).pipe(map(data => this.getPagedData(page)))
    }


    getMonitoredEvents(page: Page) {
        var batchSize = this.page.size;
        var batchNumber = this.page.pageNumber;
        var eventData =  this.httpClient.get<MonitoredEvents>(this.config.getBaseUrl() + "/api/Events/" + batchSize + "/" +  batchNumber);
        return eventData;
    }


    private getPagedData(page: Page): PagedData<MonitoredEvents> {
        const pagedData = new PagedData<MonitoredEvents>();
        page.totalElements = eventData.length;
        page.totalPages = page.totalElements / page.size;
        const start = page.pageNumber * page.size;
        const end = Math.min((start + page.size), page.totalElements);
        for (let i = start; i < end; i++){
            const eventObj = eventData[i];
            const event = new MonitoredEvents(eventObj.Id,
                eventObj.Venue,
                eventObj.Event,
                eventObj.Section,
                eventObj.EventDate,
                eventObj.Time,
                eventObj.TotalOrder,
                eventObj.TLC,
                eventObj.TicketType,
                eventObj.Source,
                eventObj.TicketPage,
                eventObj.NumberOfSeats,
                eventObj.SoldOut,
                );
            pagedData.data.push(event);
        }
        pagedData.page = page;
        return pagedData;
    }

}
```

Upload.Component.Ts code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvents(this.page);
    console.log(this.page.size);
    console.log(this.page.pageNumber);

    this.getEvents2(13,6);
    this.getEvents3(this.page);



    this.setPage({ offset: 0 });
}
```

and my methods

```
getEvents(page: Page)
  {
    this.monitoredEventService.getMonitoredEvents(this.page).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
  }

  getEvents2(batchSize, batchNumber)
  {
    this.monitoredEventService.getMonitoredEvents2(batchSize, batchNumber).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  getEvents3(page: Page){
    this.monitoredEventService.getEvents(this.page).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  setPage(pageInfo){
    this.page.pageNumber = pageInfo.offset;
    this.monitoredEventService.getEvents(this.page).subscribe(pagedData => {
      console.log(pagedData);
      this.page = pagedData.page;
      this.rows = pagedData.data;
    });

    };
```

Also here is my console log:
[image]

Whenever I log to the console my "GetMonitoredEvents" method I am able to see all the objects being returned to the console..

However when I log my "GetEvents" I see a data array of 0 being returned...

Comment: Take a read of my article on Angular state management with my library RxCache https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Comment: Which section should I refer to for solving my problem?

Comment: can u provide upload.component.ts code

Comment: what is your global variable in your code?

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar Added

Comment: @HienNguyen I'm trying to set the "eventData" being returned in "GetMonitoredEvents()" to be able to be accessed by getEvents() and getPagedData()

Comment: const eventData = []; does not create a global variable, it creates a block level variable at the imports level. I linked to my article to show you how to create proper Angular services for sharing data between components. Read the whole article and you will have an understanding of creating well defined Angular services. You don't do things in Angular with global variables. If you did want to hack something so nasty you would do it with window.eventData = []; but that would get you kicked off my team instantly if I saw that in a code review.

Comment: haha well I am fairly new to angular, so I'm still learning proper technique. However I really only need to access the returned array of objects within the service. Does the article still work for that?

Comment: @AdrianBrand I'm trying to repliate server side pagination within my ngx-datatable and it seems like in their example here: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/paging/mock-server-results-service.ts they are importing dummy data from a JSON file to a variable... where as I am using a GET method and that returned data is stuck within my method.. so I am trying to allow other methods to access that returned data. (Just to clarify what I am trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

You can change from `const eventData = [];` to `static eventData = [];`

but this way the variable is reset when you refresh page.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't really help because I need to set the global variable to an Observable<MonitoredEvents> essentially storing the returned data from getMonitoredEvents() into a variable that the other methods can easily access the data... that way my table can get the rows propagated